# Let $X$ be a topological space. If $U \subset X$ is compact and $V \subset X$ is closed, show that $U \cap V$ is compact.

Tags: general-topology

$X$ isn't assumed to be Hausdorff here.

I got stuck trying to attempt this question but here's what I attempted:

Let $\{A_{\alpha}\}$ be and open cover for $U \cap V$, I want to show that there is a finite subcover that covers $U \cap V$.

By hypothesis, we have that $U$ is compact, so for an open cover $\{B_{\alpha}\}$, there is a finite subcover so: we have that $U = B_{u_1} \cup \dots \cup B_{u_n}$.

I'm stuck here because I don't really know how to use the hypothesis that $V$ is closed here. Any hints would be helpful!

Comment: If $V$ is closed in $X$ then $U \cap V$ is closed in $U$. Therefore you may as well assume $U = X$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is to recall that a closed subset of a compact space is compact. Indeed, $V$ is closed in $X$, so $U\cap V$ is closed in $U$ by definition of the relative (subspace) topology.

Comment: Thanks! That was the information that I was missing.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Let $\{A_\alpha\}$ be an open cover of $U\cap V$. Then $\{B_\alpha\} \cup V^c$ is an open cover of $U$, which admits a finite subcover.